# When did Ubuntu get created?

Tags: 12.04

What year did Ubuntu come out to the public? Who created it? Why was it created? How popular is it today? What are the other types of Linux OS? Name them please. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Homework?

History:

http://www.netneurotic.de/mac/unix/images/UNIX.png

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3AUnix_history-simple.svg

http://www.levenez.com/unix/

http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MarkShuttleworth

Versions and release & support until dates:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases